# how to sum records in columns of a particular row with the answer in same row

Tags: php, mysql, row

How can I sum the fees, bus, and snacks and the result to show on same row under total? e.g 100+20+500 = 620.

The data

```
salary recurrent repairs_maint .....   TOTAL
=============================================
100       20      250    250  .....     620
==============================================
20   10  200      100    100.....      430
==============================================
```

The PHP code

```
<?php 
      $add=mysqli_query($conn,'SELECT SUM(salary),SUM(recurrent),SUM(repairs_maint),SUM(creditors) ,SUM(petty_cash) ,SUM(capital_expenses)from `monthly_expenditure`');
      while($row1=mysqli_fetch_array($add))
      {
        $mark=$row1['SUM(salary)'];
        $mark1=$row1['SUM(recurrent)'];
        $mark3=$row1['SUM(repairs_maint)']; 
        $mark4=$row1['SUM(creditors)'];
        $mark5=$row1['SUM(petty_cash)'];
        $mark6=$row1['SUM(capital_expenses)'];
     ?>

      <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th>Total  =</th>
        <th><?php echo $mark ?></th>
        <th><?php echo $mark1 ?></th>
        <th><?php echo $mark3 ?></th>
        <th><?php echo $mark4 ?></th>
        <th><?php echo $mark5 ?></th>
        <th><?php echo $mark6 ?></th>
```

Comment: you should use aliases

Comment: `FEES BUS  SNACKS TOTAL` - your query doesn't contain any of those columns, if that's what that is supposed to represent, unless you have HTML table headers that weren't shown.

Comment: Did you accidentally include the wrong code?

Comment: am sorry i dont know how to post question here thats the similar code i have that have been accepted

Answer (score 0):

You would start from here instead:

```
id expense value
 1 FEES      100  
 1 BUS        20   
 1 SNACKS    500    
 2 FEES       20
 2 BUS        10  
 2 SNACKS    400
```

Comment: thanks please, i want the total of FEES with id=1 and pls add another field name say bus

Comment: i want to display the total at the end of each  row and not at the buttom of the culumn

Comment: You seem to be very confused about the difference between data storage and data display.

Answer (score 0):

Your description is little bit confusing. If I understand correctly than you want to sum all given attributes for each id. Following query may work:

```
select t.id,t.a as salary,t.b as recurrent,t.c as repairs_maint,
       t.d as creditors,t.e as petty_cash,t.f as capital_expenses
       (t.a + t.b + t.c + t.d + t.e + t.f) as total
from
(SELECT SUM(salary) as a,
      SUM(recurrent) as b,
      SUM(repairs_maint) as c,
      SUM(creditors) as d,
      SUM(petty_cash) as e,
      SUM(capital_expenses) as f
from monthly_expenditure
group by id) t
group by t.id;
```